# Nested Form Groups & FromArray in Angular 8

Tags: angular8, formarray, formgroups, angular-formbuilder

I working on form which has nested form groups & form arrays but I am not able to bind values in ts.
I am new to angular so dont have much clarity on formgroup and form arrays.
below json can have multiple arrays within formgroups and nested form arrays within form group.
Here is the sample example which i want to execute and make below json structure from this form

Json using this form :

```
{
  ip:'1.2.3.4',
  create_adjacency:{
    customerName:'ABC',
    traffic_group:[{
       _display_name:'DEF',
       traffic_group_limits:{
          calls:'23' }
    }]
  }
}
```

HTML -

```
<div class="page-container pb-25 ">
      <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
          <div class="form-group custom-input select-custom-prime">
                <label>IP</label>
                <input
                   placeholder="Select"
                  formControlName="ip"
                />                  
              </div>
          <div class="row mb-20" formGroupName="create_adjacency">
            <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
              <div
                class="form-group custom-input select-custom-prime"
                >
                <label>Customer Name</label>
                <input
                   placeholder="Select"
                  formControlName="customerName"
                />
                
              </div>
            </div>
            <div formArrayName="traffic_group">
              <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                <div  
                    class="form-group custom-input mr-10 select-custom-prime" >
                  <label>Traffic group Name</label>

                  <input
                    formControlName="_display_name"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>

              <table
                class="mt-30 table table-striped table-bordered wd-98"
              >
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Traffic Group Name</th>
                    <th>Concurrent Calls</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody formGroupName="traffic_group_limits">
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <div class="">
                        <div
                          class="form-group custom-input select-custom-prime"
                        >
                          <input
                            pInputText
                            autofocus
                            disabled
                            type="text"
                            class="form-control"
                          />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <div class="">
                        <div
                          class="form-group custom-input select-custom-prime"
                        >
                          <input
                            formControlName="calls"
                            pInputText
                            autofocus
                            class="form-control"
                          />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Ts code -

```
this.firstFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      ip: [''],
      create_adjacency: this.formBuilder.group({
        customerName: ["", Validators.required],
        traffic_groups: this.formBuilder.array([this.traffic_groups])
      })

    });
  
  
  get traffic_groups(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      _display_name: ["", Validators.required],
      traffic_group_limits: this.formBuilder.group({
        "call-appearances": ["", Validators.required]
      })
    });
  }
```

Comment: Can you create stackblitz here https://stackblitz.com

Answer (score 0):

> In my opinion, as much angular has their own way of doing this, it might be a little intimidating to a beginner. So I prefer breaking down the formgroups and then constructing the final json from all the forms all together.

> .html

```
   <div class="page-container pb-25 ">
      <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
          <div class="form-group custom-input select-custom-prime">
                <label>IP</label>
                <input
                   placeholder="Select"
                  formControlName="ip"
                />                  
              </div>
          <div class="row mb-20" [formGroup]="adjacencyFormGroup">
            <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
              <div
                class="form-group custom-input select-custom-prime"
                >
                <label>Customer Name</label>
                <input
                   placeholder="Select"
                  formControlName="customerName"
                />
                
              </div>
            </div>
            <div [formGroup]="trafficFormGroup">
              <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                <div  
                    class="form-group custom-input mr-10 select-custom-prime" >
                  <label>Traffic group Name</label>

                  <input
                    formControlName="_display_name"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>

              <table
                class="mt-30 table table-striped table-bordered wd-98"
              >
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Traffic Group Name</th>
                    <th>Concurrent Calls</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody [formGroup]="trafficGroupLimit">
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <div class="">
                        <div
                          class="form-group custom-input select-custom-prime"
                        >
                          <input
                            pInputText
                            autofocus
                            disabled
                            type="text"
                            class="form-control"
                          />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <div class="">
                        <div
                          class="form-group custom-input select-custom-prime"
                        >
                          <input
                            formControlName="calls"
                            pInputText
                            autofocus
                            class="form-control"
                          />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

> .ts

```
    this.firstFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      ip: [''],
      create_adjacency: [{}]
    });

    this.adjacencyFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
        customerName: ["", Validators.required],
        traffic_groups: [[]])
      });


this.trafficFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
        _display_name: ["", Validators.required],
      traffic_group_limits: [{}]
      });
  
  
  this.trafficGroupLimit = this.formBuilder.group({
      calls: [''],
    });
```

> function to create json

```
createFormJSON() {

this.trafficFormGroup.patchValue({
  traffic_group_limits: this.trafficGroupLimit.value
});

this.adjacencyFormGroup.patchValue({
  traffic_groups: this.allTrafficGroups // store all traffic groups in this array before patching
});

this.firstFormGroup.patchValue({
  create_adjacency: this.adjacencyFormGroup.value,
});
}
```